# How do you simulate low memory conditions under macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, memory-management, appkit

When developing and debugging macOS apps, is there a way to simulate a system-wide "low memory" event or notification?

The iOS Simulator has such a feature but I can't seem to figure out an equivalent under macOS.

I'm interested in simulating a low-memory situation to see how classes like `NSPurgeableData` and `IOSurface` handle being purged.

*(Other than writing a simple application that just keeps allocating memory...)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tool on `macOS` is for simulating low memory conditions would be `memory_pressure` (example):

```
sudo memory_pressure -S -l critical
```

The command above simulates (`-S`) a memory pressure of a critical level (`-l` critical).

> **NAME**
>        memory_pressure -- Tool to apply real or simulate memory pressure on the
>        system.
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>        memory_pressure [`-l` level] | [`-p` percent_free] | [`-S` `-l` level]
>
> **OPTIONS**
>        `-l`  Apply real or simulate memory pressure (if specified alongside
>        simulate argument) on the system till low memory notifications corresponding to  are generated. Supported values are "warn" and "critical".
>
> ```
>  -p <percent_free> Allocate memory till the available memory in the system
>  is <percent_free> of total memory. If the percentage of available memory
>  to total memory on the system drops, the tool will free memory till
>  either the desired percentage is achieved or it runs out of memory to
>  free.
>
>  -S Simulate memory pressure on the system by placing it artificially for
>  <sleep_seconds> duration at the "warn" or "critical" level.
>
>  -s <sleep_seconds> Duration to wait before allocating or freeing memory
>  if applying real pressure. In case of simulating memory pressure, this is
>  the duration the system will be maintained at an artifical memory level.
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>        A tool to apply real or simulate memory pressure on the system
>
> **SEE ALSO**
>        vm_stat(1)

Answer (score 1):

From code, you can use the [setrlimit](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/setrlimit.2.html) function to control system resource consumption in your application.

Alternatively, [ulimit](https://ss64.com/osx/ulimit.html) allows control of resources launched from the Terminal

Comment: Interesting. `setrlimit` appears to control the resource usage for just the given application. Is that enough for the system to evict data from a class adopting `NSDiscardableContent`? In my application, I share `IOSurfaces` across process boundaries. The man page states that `setrlimit` affects each child process as well, but I wonder how macOS decides which process "owns" the IOSurface and thus when it can be purged. I really want to be able to run my app as normal, allocate the usual surfaces and data, and then trigger resource limits. Will `setrlimit` retroactively apply the limits?

Comment: I don't really know much about IOSurface. Perhaps you can set a really low limit and experiment to find out how `setrlimit` will affect your application.